# c++ Legacy code using method const , still need to create function that takes const method members

Tags: c++, function, constants

i have legacy c++ code that is const method :

```
Id LegacyCode::GetIdByName(const char* sName,
                          const char* pName) const
{

  long lID;
  char szProcessName[MAXPATH];
  for (int iP = 0;
       iP < iNum;
       iP++) {

      if (strnicmp(sName, "Test.exe", MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
      {       
          if (strnicmp(szProcessName, pName, MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
          {
              // If the proces name was found, return its ID.

                return (lID);
          }
      }
      else if (strnicmp(sName, "Test2.exe", MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
      {       
          if (strnicmp(szProcessName, pName, MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
          {
              // If the proces name was found, return its ID.

                return (lID);
          }
      }
      else
      {

        if (strnicmp(sName, szProcessName, MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
         return (lID);
      }
  }

  return (0);
}
```

and i like to replace it with shorter code like this using the helper function

```
Id LegacyCode::GetIdByName(const char* sName,
                          const char* pName) const
{

  long lID;
  char szProcessName[MAXPATH];
  for (int iP = 0;
       iP < iNum;
       iP++) {

      if (isProcessName(sName,pName,szProcessName))
      {          
                return (lID);

      }
      else
      {

        if (strnicmp(sName, szProcessName, MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
         return (lID);
      }
  }

  return (0);
}


bool LegacyCode::isProcessName(char* _sName,char* _pName,char* _szProcessName)
{
       if (strnicmp(_sName, "Test.exe", MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
      {       
          if (strnicmp(_szProcessName, pName, MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
          {
              // If the proces name was found, return its ID.

                return (lID);
          }
      }
      else if (strnicmp(sName, "Test2.exe", MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
      {       
          if (strnicmp(_szProcessName, pName, MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
          {
              // If the proces name was found, return its ID.

                return (lID);
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

but Unfortunately im getting the const error:

```
error C2662: 'LegacyCode::isProcessName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const LegacyCode' to 'LegacyCode &'
```

is there any way to overcome this without adding mutable to the function membres ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `LegacyCode::isProcessName` const:

```
bool LegacyCode::isProcessName(char* _sName,char* _pName,char* _szProcessName) const;
```